# Global inequality comparisons for pair<> in C++ standard

Tags: c++, math, comparison, standards, std-pair

As according to [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/pair/):

> In inequality comparisons (<, >), the first elements are compared
>   first, and only if the inequality comparison is not true for them, the
>   second elements are compared.

which translates to something like this:

```
return ((a.first < b.first) || (!(b.first < a.first) && (a.second < b.second)));
```

My quesion is, why is it so unintuitive? *What is the reasoning behind it? And are there examples where this reasoning leads to the correct answers?*

I thought the implementation will simply be:

```
return a.first < b.first && a.second < b.second
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sort of comparison is called a *[lexicographical ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)* and is one of the more natural ways to combine two different orderings into one.

The orderings that are requested in C++ are called *[strict weak orderings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_order)*.  This means that the following should be true:

- **Irreflexivity:** x < x is always false.
- **Transitivity:** If x < y and y < z, then x < z.
- **Antisymmetry:** If x < y, then y < x is always false.
- **Transitivity of Equivalence**: If x and y are incomparable and y and z are incomparable, then x and z are incomparable.

These properties are what you need in order to guarantee that you can take a list of objects and put them into sorted ascending order.  This means that you can use `std::sort` on them, or store them in a `std::set`.

You can prove with a bit of math that if you have two different strict weak orderings, then the lexicographical ordering you get by combining them as `std::pair` does is also a strict weak ordering.  The lexicographical ordering is one of the few ways that you can combine strict weak orderings to make new strict weak orderings.

However, the ordering that you've suggested is **not** a strict weak ordering and will cause certain assumptions to break.  In particular, consider the pairs (0, 5), (3, 3), and (1, 6).  Then (0, 5) is incomparable with (3, 3) and (3, 3) is incomparable with (1, 6).  However, we do indeed have that (0, 5) < (1, 6), which breaks the rule of *transitivity of equivalence*.  As a result, many sorting algorithms that assume that equivalence is transitive (which includes most major sorting algorithms) will not work correctly on your range, meaning that `std::sort` might behave incorrectly.  It also means that you also couldn't store these in a `std::set`, because the `std::set` interally stores everything in some kind of sorted order (usually a balanced binary search tree) and you might get completely wrong results.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Exactly the explanation I was looking for (+1)

Answer (score 6):

If `a.first` is less than `b.first`, then the pair is less already. There's no reason to compare the second part. Pairs implicitly sort first by their first part, just as names sort first by their first letter. "Apple" comes before "Zebra" because "A" comes before "Z", we don't compare the "p" to the "e" at all.

So if `a.first < b.first`, we're done. However, if not, we're not done. There's another way `a` can be less than `b`. That's if `b.first < a.first` is not the case, and `a.second < b.second`.

The analogy would be "Zebra" and "Zyman". "Z" is not less than "Z", but "e" is less than "y", so again, the first is less than the second.

You will sometimes see it coded this way:

```
bool operator<(const foo& a, const foo& b) {
 if (a.first < b.first) return true;
 if (a.first > b.first) return false;
 return (a.second < b.second);
}
```

I find this easier to understand intuitively, but the logic is the same:

Comment: Great explanation, adds to the answer above (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Intuitiveness is in the eye of the beholder. I actually find it quite intuitive myself.

It acts just like you do when you are comparing other sequences. For example, you would say that the string `"az"` comes before `"ba"`, right? But you don't have `'a' < 'b' && 'z' < 'a'`! The same reasoning is applied for pairs. It's not only more intuitive but it also maintains all the desirable properties of such a relation.